We shall not [glance] at [glance-appwidget]
There's an Android library named Jetpack Glance, or as Google put it, A Framework.
Anyhow, it's a library to develop Android App Widgets on top of Jetpack Compose runtime.
Long story short, there's a glance and another one glance-appwidget. Currently, each of them has about 40 questions, and both refer to the same concept. Many questions related to the concept have both tags.
Looking at their history, both are created by a single user, which I will mention in the comments, so possibly they can shed some light on the matter here.
I think merging glance-appwidget into glance is a good idea, and an even better idea is to rename it to jetpack-glance so it would be consistent with other Jetpack library tags.

Mentioning @PierreBdR

FWIW that's not how @ mentions work on Stack Exchange and so that user was not  notified.

FYI, I've pinged the user on the oldest visible question.

Considering the user hasnt visited the site in 2 years or more, however, I suspect it unlikely they'll notice the ping. It should likely be assumed that they won't contribute to the discussion here.

"Burnination at a glance"?

@PeterMortensen I'd rather merge at a glance.
